# Insert multiple rows into database (PDO) [Items separated by commas]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am writing a simple web application where the user can input data into a textarea input field, and that data will be put into the database.

I.E:

item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6

Obviously, the text area would be whatever the user inputs.
I need all of the items, input into my database but into their own rows. I've seen plenty of sites do something similar where you input a bunch of info into a text area, and separate it by commas than it's put into the database.

Thanks for any help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What code have you already wrote for this?

Comment: `explode()` will do part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = explode(',', $_POST['textarea']); // this will contain an array of each item $array[0] will be item1 etc.
```

You may want to handle the space after the comma too with a trim() https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_ltrim.asp so that you don't end up with whitespace in your DB.

Then do your insert statement:

```
$statement = $PDO->prepare("INSERT INTO table(column1) VALUES(:item)");
foreach($array as $item) {
 //SQL to insert the array element      
  $statement->execute(array(
      "item" => $item
  ));
} //Something like this will do the trick...
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: You can and you should `prepare` only __once__, before `foreach` starts

Comment: I'd put the `$statement = $PDO...` outside of the `foreach()`, because the beauty of prepared statements is that they can be reused. Better still is probably collecting all parameters and dynamically creating a single statement that `INSERT`s multiple rows at once.